# Javascript not working in AJAX response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Below code is the AJAX response to another page. I have added onclick event to table row and written javascript code to handle it. But javascript code doesn't work.Is this wrong way of coding or there is any problem in code. Suggest me a simple solution

```
<?php

echo '<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    function clicked(){
      alert("I am an alert box!");
    }
    </script>';
$q = $_GET['q'];
include 'db_connect.php';
$sql="SELECT name,address,mobile,email,pan,tan FROM client WHERE name = '$q'";
$sql_bill="SELECT clientname,financialyear,receiptno,amount,ddate,type,chequeno,category FROM billing WHERE clientname = '$q'";
$sql_total="SELECT SUM(amount) AS TotalAmount FROM billing";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$result_bill = mysql_query($sql_bill);
$result_total = mysql_query($sql_total);
$total= mysql_fetch_array($result_total);
echo "<h4><b>Client details</b></h4><table align='center' border='2'>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Mobile</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>PAN</th>
        <th>VAT TIN</th>
    </tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['mobile'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['pan'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['tan'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<h4><b>Payment received details</b></h4><table align='center' border='2'>
    <tr>
        <th>Client Name</th>
        <th>Financial Year</th>
        <th>Receipt No</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Chequeno</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_bill))
{
  echo "<tr onclick=\"clicked()\">";
  echo "<td>" . $row['clientname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['financialyear'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['receiptno'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ddate'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['chequeno'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['category'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['amount'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td colspan=7>Total</td>";
echo "<td>".$total['TotalAmount'].  "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: please give context to the problem

Comment: This isn't an AJAX request?

Comment: I don't see any ajax request here. How exactly does your code "not work"?

Comment: This AJAX code looks like it takes GET requests. The best way is to directly load this page on your browser and pass the GET parameter in the address. If you see the desired output, your AJAX is working.

Comment: This is not AJAX request, this is a response php file to AJAX request made by another page

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 1:**

Look in the console (F12), What happens when you click on a tr?

The following fiddle replicates your code and works:
http://jsfiddle.net/Yaj44/

---

**Edit 2:**

I think it has something to do with the way you call the data.

- Put the function in your **main** page,
- then call the AJAX.
- Set innerHTML of specific div with responseData.

If you do it in that order, it might work.

---

Your way to adding this functionality is very dirty..

If you use JQuery, you can add on the end:

```
$('tr').click(function() {
    alert('Do something on click!');
});
```

mysql_fetch_array is outdated, use mysqli (or PDO) instead.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: I have changed my code. Still no response. The issues u mentioned above are not solution to my problem.

Comment: I tried to watch console. On clicking on a row, Uncaught ReferenceError: clicked is not defined

Comment: which means the function doesn't exist yet. Try putting the function in the main page. My guess is that the javascript given from the AJAX is not run.

Comment: Adding javascript code on the AJAX requested page, works

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of your script code:

```
echo <<<EOD
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function clicked(){
      alert("I am an alert box!");
    }
  </script>
EOD;
```

Comment: You must be sure that EOD; is in beginning of line. No character allowed before and after that.

Comment: Ya. Its in the way u mentioned above. Still not working

Comment: I don't see any error in your javascript code. If you have tr filling with your php, it must work. You can test this script by adding onclick event to total tr.